# Perl: slicing an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

The output of the code below is always empty. Not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any help. How do I get to the values of a key in a specific hash in an array of hashes?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dot1 = ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
my %dot2 = ('a'=>3,'b'=>4);
my %dot3 = ('a'=>5,'b'=>6);
my %dot4 = ('a'=>7,'b'=>8);

my @array = (%dot1,%dot2,%dot3,%dot4);

my %x = $array[2];
my $y = $x->{'a'};

print "$y \n";
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: You should be getting a compilation error with this code; `x` is a hash, not a hash reference. Also, `array` is not an array of 4 hash references; it is an array of 16 scalars.

Comment: `@array` is not an array of hashes.  It is a flat 16-element array.

Comment: Flat array of scalars - what method/structure can I do to house the four hashes?

Comment: How many times do I need to recommend that you read [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)? :-)

Comment: Sorry @DaveCross, been reading up since. Now that I see by ref actually points to a memory location rather than getting a copy, the picture is much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an array of hash references, you need to say so explicitly.

```
my @array = (\%dot1, \%dot2, \%dot3, \%dot4);
my %x = %{$array[2]};
my $y = $x{a};
print "$y\n";
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Understand the %{$array[2]} part.

Comment: I'm dereferencing the hash reference so that we can assign an actual `hash` to `%x`. You could also work directly with the reference with `$my x = $array[2]; my $y = $x->{a}`. The key point is storing hash references in the array, instead of storing the expanded contents of each hash in the array.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have an *array of hashes*. You have an array that looks like a hash, where the keys `a` and `b` will be there four times each, in relatively random order.

```
print Dumper \@array;
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          1,
          'b',
          2,
          'a',
          3,
          'b',
          4,
          'a',
          5,
          'b',
          6,
          'a',
          7,
          'b',
          8
        ];
```

Afterwards, you are using `$x->{a}`, which is the syntax to take the key `a` from the hashref `$x`, but you only ever declared a hash `%a`. That in turn breaks, because you give it an odd-sized list of one value.

Instead, add references to the hashes to your array. That way you will get a multi-level data structure instead of a flat list. Then make the `x` variable a scalar `$x`.

```
my %dot1 = ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
my %dot2 = ('a'=>3,'b'=>4);
my %dot3 = ('a'=>5,'b'=>6);
my %dot4 = ('a'=>7,'b'=>8);

my @array = (\%dot1,\%dot2,\%dot3,\%dot4); # here


my $x = $array[2]; # here
my $y = $x->{'a'};

print "$y \n";
```

This will print `5`.

You should read up on data structures in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Very clear. And now see the zero base part clarified too. Many thanks @simbabque.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is add references to your hashes to your `@array`, otherwise perl will evaluate the hashes in list context.

```
my @array = (\%dot1,\%dot2,\%dot3,\%dot4);
my $x = $array[2];
my $y = $x->{'a'};

print "$y \n";
```

Comment: Thanks @sparkeyG. I see the problem now.

Comment: Though not entire sure I understand the $x since $array[2] is not a scalar but %dot2. Also, just want to confirm that in Perl, arrays and hashes do not start with zero, right?

Comment: The value at ```$array[2]``` is a reference to ```%dot3``` (note that arrays in perl are zero referenced.) $x is a scalar containing the reference.