# Perl: How to access an array in a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, nested

I have a sample hash with an array inside, but it seems wrong the way I access the elements of the array. I do it this way:

```
%Hash_Object = (
  "Property1","value-1",
  "Property2",("value-2","value-3")
);

print $Hash_Object{Property2}[1];
#blank output!
```

It is supposed to print out "value-3", but it doesn't.

Comment: You don't have an array in your hash. You have a list. I'm looking for a duplicate with a good explanation. In the meantime, you need to use `[]` inside the hash assignment.

Comment: relevant, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40044519/1331451

Comment: `%Hash_Object = (
  "Property1","value-1",
  "Property2",["value-2","value-3"]
);`

Comment: I bet there are ten questions like this one, but I cannot find them. Answering instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have an array in your hash. You have a list. Keep the following in mind:

- Lists are not the same as arrays in Perl
- Lists are flat structures
- Arrays are lists

If you put an array into a list, it will be treated as another list, and lists are flat:

```
(1, 2, (3, 4, 5), (6, (7)))
```

is equal to

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

If you want to build more complex data structures, you need to use *references*. There are two ways to make a reference. You can either reference a variable by using `\` like this

```
my @foo = qw(a b c);
my $ref = \@foo;
```

or by constructing it directly as an anonymous reference that you then assign to a variable.

```
my $ref = [ qw(a b c) ];
my $ref2 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

To make a hash reference, use curly braces `{}`.

```
my $ref = { a => 1, b => 2 };
```

References are scalar values, so they are themselves just a single flat value. That's why you need to dereference them in order to get to the value that's *inside* of them (really it's not inside, it's *referenced*).

```
%Hash_Object = (
  "Property1","value-1",
  "Property2",["value-2","value-3"]
);
$Hash_Object{Property2}[1];
$Hash_Object{Property2}->[1]; # or like this with ->
```

You already knew how to do that. You can also use the `->` operator in front of every new dereference. Some people find that clearer to read.

For more information, see perlreftut and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) as well as [Mike Friedman's excellent blog post about lists and arrays](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

---

Your example is not very well written code. Here are some improvement.

- variable names should be lower-case
- use the *fat comma* `=>` for hash assignments
- you don't need double quotes `""` if you're not interpolating
- always put commas after the final element
- don't name things for what type they are, name them for what they represent
- a hash is not an object
- you need to use `my` when declaring a new variable

```
my %example = (
    Property1 => 'value-1',
    Property2 => [
        'value-2',
        'value-3',
    ],
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use **use warnings;** and **use strict;** in top of the program.

If you use this it display the following errors

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at array.pl line 3.
Can't use string ("value-2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at array.pl line 8
```

**In perl, where list are flatten together**.

so the first error is

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at array.pl line 3
```

Hashes must has pairs of keys and value. So the elements of the hash should not be an odd number.

Your code should be

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %Hash_Object = (
  "Property1"=>["value-1"],
  "Property2"=>["value-2","value-3"]
);

print $Hash_Object{Property2}[1];
```

Comment: I didn't even see the odd number. Well spotted.

Comment: The last assumption that each element should be an array reference is not correct. You don't know if OP wants that. They just showed that there is _an array_ in `Property2`.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for your comment. Just now I knew it.

Answer (score 0):

Array values should be in square brackets, thanks simbabque

```
%Hash_Object = (
  "Property1","value-1",
  "Property2",["value-2","value-3"]
);

print $Hash_Object{Property2}[1];
```

Comment: "Array values should be in square brackets" - well, only when you want a reference to that array (which you do in this case, because you're building a complex data structure).